# php process goes unresponsive when making a HTTP POST method call using GuzzleHttp

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle, laravel-passport

I am using guzzle HTTP client to issue a password grant based access token after successful user login. I am using passport package for oauth and I have done all the setup which includes the Password Grant Client it creates. In my login controller I override the `sendLoginResponse` method of the `AuthenticatesUsers` trait so as to issue an access token on successful email/password authentication

```
public function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
{

    try {
        Log::debug("Auth attempt sucessful, obtaining access_token for user :: ".$request->email);

        $client = new Client();

        $token_response = $client->post(config('app.url').'/oauth/token', [
            'form_params' => [
                'grant_type' => 'password',
                'client_id' => config('auth.password_grant.client.id'),
                'client_secret' => config('auth.password_grant.client.secret'),
                'username' => $request->email,
                'password' => $request->password,
                'scope' => '*',
            ],
        ]);

        if($token_response->getStatusCode()!=200) {
            Log:error("Login failed to generate Access Token");
            throw new InvalidCredentialsException();
        }
        $request->session()->regenerate();
        $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);
        $data = json_decode((string) $token_response->getBody(), true);
        Cookie::queue('refresh_token',$data->refresh_token,config('auth.tokens.refresh.expire.days')*1440);

        Log::debug("Adding Bearer token to Authorization header");
        return response()->view('dashboard', [
            'expires_in' => $data->expires_in
        ], 200)->header('Authorization', $data->token_type.' '.$data->access_token);            
    } catch(Exception $e){
        Log::error('Error :: '.$e->getMessage());
        throw $e;
    }
}
```

The whole PHP process goes unresponsive when I make this post request, and there are no errors in any of the logs. Exactly at this line

`$token_response = $client->post($token_url, .......`

I ran this in Debug session; and the URL, Client ID and Secret are generated correctly via configuration properties; the only Exception I could see was a `FileNoFoundException` that occurs when it does find any cache key for throttle login and that all happens much before this call is made and the app proceeds to authenticate the user.

When I make this very request with same parameters through Postman or via `artisan` `tinker` I can get a response with `access_token`, `refresh_token` and `expires_in` data.

Comment: wrap your code with try/catch block first, and then dd the error

Comment: wrapped in try catch, I still don't see an exception printed to logs or thrown

Comment: By default guzzelhttp waits "forever" for the request to arrive. You could and should set a [timeout](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#timeout) in the client options to prevent this to wait for too long.

Comment: `$client->post(config('app.url').'/oauth/token', [
                'form_params' => [
                    'grant_type' => 'password',
                    'client_id' => config('...),
                    'client_secret' => config('...'),
                    'username' => $request->email,
                    'password' => $request->password,
                    'scope' => '',
                ],
            ],[
                'timeout' => 5, // Response timeout
                'connect_timeout' => 5, // Connection timeout
            ]);` is this the right way to add timeouts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of hours with 'Hit And Trial' does really save you 10 minutes of going through 'Documentation'.

Turns out I really don't have to do all this heavy lifting [this link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript) shows how we can add the `\Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class,` to `web` middleware in `app/http/Kernel.php` which takes care of generating ApiToken for first party apps such as the React JS which I'd be using to consume my own API.

While that solved the intent of writing all this code, I'm still not sure what was causing the process unresponsiveness making the access_token from within the php code.